# How to get item by Id using Vue 3 Composition API using Axios

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Im struggling using Axios and useRoute using Axios with Composition API. Here is the code on how to do it in using the Option API, how do I recreate it, the Vue-router docs not well documented at all right now.

```js
async created() {
    const result = await axios.get(`https://localhost:5001/api/artists/${this.$route.params.id}`
    );
    const artist = result.data;
    this.artist = artist;
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert that code to Composition API:

1. `created()` hook is effectively the same timing as [`setup()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#setup), so put that code in `setup()`.
2. `this.$route` can be accessed via [`useRoute()`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#useroute) (from `vue-router@4`).
3. `artist` can be declared as a data [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref), returning it from `setup()` if used in the template.
4. To reactively fetch data from the API based on the `id` parameter, use [`watch`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watch) on `route.params.id`. This `watch` call returns a [function that stops the watcher](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#stopping-the-watcher), which is useful if you need to conditionally unwatch the reference.

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

export default {
  // 1
  setup() {
     const route = useRoute() // 2
     const artist = ref(null) // 3

     // 4
     const unwatch = watch(() => route.params.id, (newId, oldId) => {
       const result = await axios.get(`https://localhost:5001/api/artists/${newId}`)
       artist.value = result.data

       // run only once
       unwatch()
     })

     return {
       artist
     }
  }
}
```